# How to retrieve Facebook user post with criteria?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have an application which syncs user data from source to destination.

Current Use case: Sync Facebook photo to dropbox.

I have implemented following steps to retrieve user photos:

1. Take user access token; then exchange it with extended access token.
2. Save the extended access token to DB.
3. Poll to Facebook on Timeline Photo album with the help of extended access token and using `lastSync` check to check if new photo is present.
4. If there are any new photos available, then get those photos and upload them to user's Dropbox account folder (assuming that we have Oauth permissions for user's Dropbox account). Finally update `lastsync` in DB as currect timestamp.

My new use case is to get Facebook posts/photos with criteria like if n number of comments are posted to a photo/post; then retrieve it and sync it to Dropbox. In this case; it can be a old post or photo too.

I tried it with Real-Time update subscription but it didn't helped me much.

Any help on the above use case will be very helpful.

BTW, I am using `Restfb`.

Comment: The current API has no built-in method for that; you would have to get _all_ the posts/photos and check the number of comments yourself – and that is hardly feasible, it would take a lot of time to go through “all” of the user’s posts. (“All” in quotes because not even that is realistically possible – you can only “go back” so far, after a certain point you will simply not get data any more.)

Comment: i tried it out with real-time update subscription but they notify only for new stuff, say i had subscribed for photo they notify me only if photo is added not if any comment is added or the photo is liked. Is there any API to get such scenario is use